# how to make pivot query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have a table `criteria` whose structure is like this:

```
+----------+------+-------+
| criteria | user | total |
+----------+------+-------+
| xxxxxxxx | xx   | xxx   |
+----------+------+-------+
```

I have a problem to creating a query.  I want make a pivot query from a single table, and I have this data:

```
+----------+------+-------+
| criteria | user | total |
+----------+------+-------+
|    F1    |  A1  |  17   |
|    F2    |  A1  |  9    |
|    F3    |  A1  |  6    |
|    F4    |  A1  |  4    |
|    F1    |  A2  |  19   |
|    F2    |  A2  |  6    |
|    F3    |  A2  |  2    |
|    F4    |  A2  |  8    |
+----------+------+-------+
```

and i want to make query pivot like this :

```
+----------+------+-------+------+-------+
| criteria | user | total | user | total |
+----------+------+-------+------+-------+
|    F1    |  A1  |  17   |  A2  |  19   |
|    F2    |  A1  |  9    |  A2  |  6    |
|    F3    |  A1  |  6    |  A2  |  2    |
|    F4    |  A1  |  4    |  A2  |  8    |
+----------+------+-------+------+-------+
```

Can somebody help me write a query to get the above result?

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Comment: Why not have headings of `| criteria | A1 total | A2 total |`?  That's the classic "pivot".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be handled well by a self-join rather than a pivot.  You can `JOIN` together the `criteria` table on itself using the `criteria` column:

```
SELECT c1.criteria AS criteria, c1.user AS user, c1.total AS total,
    c2.user AS user, c2.total AS total
FROM criteria c1 INNER JOIN criteria c2
ON c1.criteria = c2.criteria
WHERE c1.user < c2.user
```

Comment: here it is ... this works , but still there is no duplication of user where the ' A1 ' and ' A2 ' is still mixed in one column , is there a way to separate it ? so that the user ' A1 ' and ' A2 ' do not mix ?

Comment: I added a `WHERE` clause to show only distinct user pairs.